# Passing the cycle from the beginning to the end (Or vice versa)

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Good afternoon guys, such a question, I'm doing an array with brute force. I can't understand why assigning a value from the last element of the FrezeTree array to the BufferObject works in the Start() method, but this does not happen in Update.
So.
At the start of the scene, there is a search for all objects with the Tree tag (This is a temporary and debag solution):

```
FrezeTree = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tree");
```

Then, this list is passed to the array:

```
public GameObject[] FrezeTree;
```

Next, I'm trying to pass one element from the array to another object (This happens in the Start() method):

```
foreach (GameObject gm in FrezeTree)
 {
   BufferObject = gm;
 }
```

But it turns out that only the last element is transmitted (Because of My own crookedness, since I don't know how to fix it yet). Why do I need a Buffer Object? From it I get the X position of the object, which I use for other purposes. The idea is to transfer one element from the array to the object, and when the object ceases to exist (Gets the null status), it goes to the element above / below (No matter in what order). Yes, I know that in what I have given above and I do not feel that I am trying to make a transition or skip an element from the array. I found various solutions on the great Internet, but the result was always the same, gets the last element and does not choose another one. That's why I turned here.

Comment: I don't really understand your goal yet but .. well in your lool your again and again overwrite `BufferObject = gm` with the current object iterating the array ... so it should be pretty obvious that this basically just is a more expensive way of writing `BufferObject = FrezeTree[FreezeTree.Length - 1];` ...

Comment: What is your **actual** goal? What are you trying to achieve in the bigger picture?

Comment: @derHugo , At the beginning of the scene, the NPC finds all the trees on the stage, then finds the one closest to him (by array) and goes to cut it down one by one...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I figured out how to implement everything myself. So, the code:

```
public GameObject[] FrezeTree; //Array of all objects in the scene
private void Start()
{
 FrezeTree = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tree"); //Finding all objects with a tag (I do not recommend using tags due to the lack of code navigation)
}
private GameObject FindClosestTarget()
{
    return False True.Where(t => t).FirstOrDefault(); //Assigning and sorting an array with objects from the scene, thanks @derHugo 
}

 void Update()
{
  BufferObject = FindClosestTarget(); //will be Assigned the next element of the array, in case the current will become "null"
 if (BufferObject == null)
 {
  Debug.Log("debug for (BufferObject == null)"); //arbitrary code in the case that any object on the stage left.
 }
}
```

P.S. This code is perfect for creating a simple AI for NPCs in your game. It's not perfect, but at least something is better than nothing :) Thanks @derHugo

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to

- set one closest target object
- wait until it is destroyed
- go to the next closest target object

You could do this by simply checking whether the `BufferObject` is already set and still alive like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

public GameObject BufferObject;

private void Update ()
{
    // This means BufferObject is either not assigned yet or was destroyed
    if(!BufferObject)
    {
        BufferObject = FindClosestTarget();
    }
}

private GameObject FindClosestTarget ()
{
    // Get all currently existing trees
    // since this happens only once in a while it should be okey to repeat this call
    return GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tree")
        // order them by distance
        .OrderBy(gm => (transform.position - gm.transform.position).sqrMagnitude)
        // get the first one or null if there was none
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

This way it would also take trees that are spawned later into account.

If you rather want to cache this array only once you can still do this like

```
private GameObject [] trees;

public GameObject BufferObject;

private void Start ()
{
    trees = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Tree");
}

private void Update ()
{
    // This means BufferObject is either not assigned yet or was destroyed
    if(!BufferObject)
    {
        BufferObject = FindClosestTarget();
    }
}

private GameObject FindClosestTarget ()
{
    // First filter out any null or destroyed objects
    return trees.Where(t => t)
        // Then order the rest by distance
        .OrderBy(gm => (transform.position - gm.transform.position).sqrMagnitude)
        // Then pick the first one or null if there isn't any
        .FirstOrDefault();
}
```

See

- [Linq `Where`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.where)
- [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)
- [Linq `FirstOrDefault`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault)
- [implicit `UnityEngine.Object.bool` operator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object-operator_Object.html)

Comment: This is of course good, but when an object disappears from the scene (that is, the object is removed from the scene altogether) I get: MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it. Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object. How to win it? The code I used: This is from the first example

Comment: I don't know/see how exactly you are consuming the `BufferObject` but you will of course need the same check `if(BufferObject)` in order to be sure there currently is a valid object

Comment: At the start of the scene, the object exists (That's for sure), the inspector shows that the object is found and the NPC "sees" it, after the NPC broke this tree, it is removed from the scene (another script responsible for this hangs on the tree and is in no way related to the script that I am tormenting now), after which the NPC stops in place and I get an error that I wrote earlier, that is: Missing Reference Exception: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object

Comment: From which component/code line do you get that error?

Comment: float localPositionAmount = BufferObject.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;

Comment: This line complains that the object does not exist. In the inspector in Unity I check and it is really written there (missing Game Object)

Comment: That is, it does not move to the next element in the array.

Comment: As said in that other component you should check e.g. `if(BufferObject){ float localPositionAmount = BufferObject.transform.position.x - transform.position.x;  ...... }` I don't see why it shouldn't go o the next object except there doesn't exist any

Comment: I have already figured out and changed your code to the state I need :)

Comment: I just restarted Unity and the code stopped throwing an exception, it's possible that there was some extra garbage somewhere or something like that. Because I only restarted Unity, and I'm writing the code in Visual Studio 2019